# Get DNS TCP TLS time under Android

Tags: java, android, https

I'm doing something for connection qualities, And I need establish a https connection and monitor it's total time and its DNS query time, TCP connect time, TLS connect time.

Under Golang I know [ClientTrace](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/#ClientTrace) will do this http tracing thing, Under Android with Java, I cant find similar interfaces

Any Insight?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use OkHttp library to make your https connection and add interceptor to log the information.

Comment: [interceptors](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/#interceptors) seems only get the total time

Comment: You can get more information from the `Request` and `Response`. Such as `request.headers()` and `response.handshake()`.

Comment: It did have some Infos, but just do not have time things :)